# Create all possible n-tuples from n vectors in Matlab, ordered in a specific way

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Consider `n` row vectors in Matlab, each of size `1xU`. For example,

```
U=20;
n=3;
sU=[U U U];
vectors = arrayfun(@(x) {1:x}, sU);
```

where `vector{1}` is the first row vector, `vector{2}` is the second row vector,..., `vector{n}` is the last row vector.

We create the matrix `Tcoord` of size `U^n x n` reporting all the possible `n`-tuples from the `n` row vectors. For each row `i` of `Tcoord`, `Tcoord(i,1)` is an element of the first row vector, `Tcoord(i,2)` is an element of the second row vector, ... , `Tcoord(i,n)` is an element of the last row vector.

```
Tcoord_temp = cell(1,n);
[Tcoord_temp{:}] = ndgrid(vectors{:}); 
Tcoord_temp = cat(n+1, Tcoord_temp{:});
Tcoord = reshape(Tcoord_temp,[],n);
```

Suppose now that I **augment** each of the `n` row vectors of `3` elements. For example,

```
vectors_augmented{1}=[vectors{1} 8 9 10];
vectors_augmented{2}=[vectors{2} 11 12 13];
vectors_augmented{3}=[vectors{3} 14 15 16];
```

I then create a matrix similar to `Tcoord` but now using `vectors_augmented`.

```
Tcoord_temp = cell(1,n);
[Tcoord_temp{:}] = ndgrid(vectors_augmented{:}); 
Tcoord_temp = cat(n+1, Tcoord_temp{:});
Tcoord_augmented = reshape(Tcoord_temp,[],n); %(U+3)^nxn
```

I would like your help to **re-order** the rows of the matrix `Tcoord_augmented` in a matrix `Tcoord_augmented_reshape` such that

- `Tcoord_augmented_reshape(1:U^n,:)` is equal to `Tcoord`.
- The remaining rows of `Tcoord_augmented_reshape` contains the other left rows of `Tcoord_augmented`.

Comment: That code looks familiar...

Comment: It really does, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to build an auxiliary zero-one matrix the same size as `Tcoord_augmented` and sort rows based on that:

```
aug_size = [3 3 3]; % augment size of each vector. Not necessarily equal
vectors_aux = arrayfun(@(a) {[false(1,U) true(1, a)]}, aug_size);
T_aux = cell(1,n);
[T_aux{:}] = ndgrid(vectors_aux{:}); 
T_aux = cat(n+1, T_aux{:});
T_aux = reshape(T_aux,[],n); 
[~, ind] = sortrows(T_aux, n:-1:1); % indices of stably sorting the rows.
% Most significant column is rightmost, as per your code
Tcoord_augmented_reorder = Tcoord_augmented(ind, :);
```